# is_search was called incorrectly

Tags: wp-query, hooks, search

I created a search form which searching by category filter and keyword input. The search form code is here-

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get" role="search" class="dropdown-form">
                <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <?php
                            wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                                'show_option_all'   => 'all categories',
                                'class'             => 'search_cats'
                            ));
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Search anything...', 'onepro'); ?>" name="s">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <button type="submit"><i class="ion-android-arrow-forward"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Then I added the `pre_get_posts` hook to bottom of the `functions.php` file-

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function() {
  global $wp_query;
  if (is_search()) {
    $cat = intval($_GET['cat']);
    $cat = ($cat > 0) ? $cat : '';
    $wp_query->query_vars['cat'] = $cat;
  }
});
```

The search form is working as well. But the bellow notice is appearing on where I used `WP_Query()` to display the post categories -

> Notice: is_search was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\onepro\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3996

Here is the query code-

```
    global $wp_query;
    global $paged;
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'    => $atts['show_posts'],
        'paged'             => $paged,
    ));

    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :

        $all_cat_slug = array();
        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
            $category = get_the_category();
            foreach( $category as $cat ){
                array_push($all_cat_slug, $cat->slug);
            }
        endwhile;
        $all_cat_slug = array_unique( $all_cat_slug );

    endif;

        <!--Portfolio Filter-->
        <div class="row filters_row text-left">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="blogs_filters">
                <li data-filter="*" class="active"><?php echo esc_html__('all', 'onepro-essential'); ?></li>
                <?php
                foreach( $all_cat_slug as $cs ){
                    $catname = get_category_by_slug( $cs );
                    echo '<li data-filter=".category-'. $cs .'">'. $catname->name .'</li>';
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The error notice occurs before the categories shown
The error screenshot-
[image]
 How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm tested your code and I don't get the warning reported. Is there any other code involved?

Comment: what does it mean exactly "where I used WP_Query()"?

Comment: @DaveRomsey I updated the question with other code that is involved with the error.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I've just updated the question with the query code. The error occurs before the categories shown.

Answer (score 5):

### The *Why* part

In the core `is_search()` function there's a check if the global `$wp_query` is set:

```
global $wp_query;

if ( ! isset( $wp_query ) ) {
    _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, 
       __( 'Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run.
            Before then, they always return false.' ), '3.1.0' );
    return false;
}
```

Note that you're unsetting it with:

```
$wp_query = null;
```

just before you create a new `WP_Query` subquery, that calls `is_search()` when `pre_get_posts` fires.

That's when the `_doing_it_wrong()` is activated.

### Workaround

Always try to use the *main query*, instead of extra `WP_Query` sub-queries if possible, to avoid running extra database queries.

To target the main search query in the front-end, we can use:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q ) {
    if ( 
            ! is_admin()         // Only target the front-end
         && $q->is_main_query()  // Target the main query
         && $q->is_search()      // Target a search query
    ) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the answer. For more info check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @birgire. Got a similar issue here with the following error message and got it fixed up by commenting out the line : `$wp_query = null;`

Error message:

> Notice : is_home was called incorrectly . Conditional query tags do
>   not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return
>   false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This
>   message was added in version 3.1.0.) in (MYsyspath)/functions.php on
>   line 4146

And it worked, the culprit was the global variable unset action on my `index.php`

```
$wp_query = null; to //$wp_query = null;
```